# PHP Bingo Script - echo certain numbers

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I want to echo 6 rows and 6 columns of numbers. The first row has to be 10-20, next row 20-30 etc. I wanted to echo 6 numbers all in one row at once, so the code stays a bit clean and efficient. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

This is the code i have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Indzendopdracht 051R3</title>
</head>

<body>
<?PHP

function printBingocard(){
$bingoNumbers = array(
    "numbers" => array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)
);

$rand_keys = array_rand($bingoNumbers, 1);  


    foreach($bingoNumbers as $bingoNumbers){
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";


    if($bingoNumbers > 10 and < 20){
    echo "<td>" . $bingoNumbers[array_rand($bingoNumbers)] . "<br />" . "</td>";
    }
    else{
        echo "";
    }


    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    }
}

printBingocard();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the array with  the numbers inside an array called "numbers" inside $bingoNumbers array.

So when you loop over it you gotta use that "numbers" array..
Like this...

```
 foreach($bingoNumbers["numbers"] as $bn){
   if($bn > 10 && $bn < 20){
    echo "<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] . "<br />" . "</td>";
   }
 }
```

Also, you used the word AND, instead of && in your comparison, and didnt include the variable on the second comparison.

```
  $bungoNumbers > 10 and < 20        should be        $bn>10 && $bn<20
```

So now, to actually echo out the table as you want.  You need to put each row into another array, so that you can echo them back to the table later, in the correct order.  Since the values of the keys is random.

Like so...

```
$rows=array();

foreach($bingoNumbers["numbers"] as $bn){
  if($bn > 10 && $bn <= 20){
   $rows["row1"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] ."</td>";
  }
  if($bn > 20 && $bn <= 30){
   $rows["row2"][]= "<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] ."</td>";
  }
  if($bn > 30 && $bn <= 40){
   $rows["row3"][]= "<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] ."</td>";
  }
  if($bn > 40 && $bn <= 50){
   $rows["row4"][]= "<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] ."</td>";
  } 
  if($bn > 50 && $bn <= 60){
   $rows["row5"][]= "<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] ."</td>";
  } 
  if($bn > 60 && $bn <= 70){
   $rows["row6"][]= "<td>" . $bingoNumbers["numbers"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["numbers"])] ."</td>";
  }   
}
```

Then you need to loop over that rows array, and loop over its contents to echo the rows.

Like so...

```
  echo "<table>";
  foreach($rows as $row){
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach($row as $r){
        echo $r;
     }
     echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Hope that helps :)
Heres a [PHP SANDBOX](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8284546000d1386a22317424d4b1979488fd04af) of your completed code

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to explain everything. It makes so much more sense now!

Comment: It now outputs 10 rows and 6 columns. It needs to be 6 rows and 6 columns. Row 1 needs to have the value 10-20, row 2 the value 20-30 etc. What needs to be changed?